# How do you interact with a file named "!!"?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Out of rage, I quit `vim` by using `:wq!!!`. This created a file named `!!`.

Given that `!!` references the previous command, attempting to interact with it yields interesting results.

I tried `rm ./!!` and `rm -- !!`. Both would pull in the previous command (as it should).

An easy solution is to simply start a shell that doesn't treat `!!` like anything special, but that's too easy.

How can I properly interact with the file in bash?

Comment: `rm -- '!!'` or `rm -- \!\!` Both is workable on bash 4.3.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove file with name like `!!`, just escape it:

```
rm \!\!
```

or just `rm !<TAB>` -> `rm \!\!`

Answer (score 1):

With Bash, you can use rm -- '!!'

```
$ cat '!!'
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
$ ls 
!!
$ rm '!!'
$ ls 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Excape the "!" character with backslash. Or disable history expansion.

```
set +o histexpand
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find it easier to wrap file/directory names created with special characters using single quotes:

```
rm '!!'
rm -rf '&$dir'
```

Comment: For `!!`, that works in `bash`, but not in `(t)csh` (where that history expansion feature comes from).

Comment: What does `rm -rf '&$dir'` is supposed to do?

Comment: `rm -rf '&$dir'` is for special character created directories. I have come across users who created directories as such from poor cmdline syntax. The `-f` to force and not prompt, but that can be omitted if you wish to constantly be prompted.

Answer (score 0):

```
\!\!
```

You should get a terminal which can automate this for you, in my Terminal.app I can drop anything with a name of like

```
√ƒ¸[|¸ƒ¸|[∂[ƒ√[[ƒ||[]√ƒ√¸•[]¸√[®¸@£|[¸|[]]ƒ¸é[
```

And it will escape it for me automatically. Consider getting that, to avoid asking these types of questions in the future.

Comment: That was unnecessarily mean (considering that the question was asked partly out of general curiosity since the OP had a solution at hand already). Also, in many contexts I do really not want the terminal to interfere with what I type because even the smartest terminal is so much more stupid than I am, short of the singularity. And after the singularity more than ever I really really do not want the terminal to interfere either, now that I think of it.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Why is answering a question, and the giving a tip considered mean? It was with good intent.